# CALCULATED column issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

Scenario:
Need to get difference between two dates (Start Date, End Date) in months, and if End Date is blank, then display "Open".

I am trying:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK[End Date], " ", (DATEDIF([End Date], [Start Date], “M”)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([End Date]), "Open", DATEDIF([End Date], [Start Date], "M"))
```

OR

```
=IF(ISBLANK([End Date]), "Open", Text(DATEDIF([End Date], [Start Date], "M")))
```

**Documentation**: [Calculate the difference between two dates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)#calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates)